# Moving all .csv files which match specific text pattern from multiple subfolders to new folder [Python]

Tags: python, loops, pattern-matching, subdirectory, file-copying

I see many answers on here to *similar questions* but I cannot seem to adapt it quite yet due to my budding Python skill. I'd like to save the time of individually grabbing the data sets that contain what I need for analysis in R, but my scripts either don't run or seem to do what I need.

I need to 1) loop through a sea of subfolders in a parent folder, 2) loop through the bagillion .csv files in those subs and pick out the 1 that matters (matching text below) and 3) copy it over to a new clean folder with only what I want.

**What I have tried:**

1)

```
import os, shutil, glob

src_fldr = 'C:/project_folder_withsubfolders'; 

dst_fldr = 'C:/project_folder_withsubfolders/subfolder_to_dump_into'; 

try:
  os.makedirs(dst_fldr); ## it creates the destination folder
except:
  print ("Folder already exist or some error");

for csv_file in glob.glob(src_fldr+'*statistics_Intensity_Sum_Ch=3_Img=1.csv*'):
    shutil.copy2(csv_file, dst_fldr);
```

where the text *statistics_Intensity_Sum* etc is the exact pattern I need for the file to copy over

- **this didn't actually copy anything over**

2. Making a function that will do this:

```
srcDir = 'C:/project_folder_withsubfolders'
dstDir = 'C:/project_folder_withsubfolders/subfolder_to_dump_into'
def moveAllFilesinDir(srcDir, dstDir):
    files = os.listdir(srcDir)
    for f in files:
        if f.find("statistics_Intensity_Sum_Ch=3_Img=1"):
            shutil.move(f, dstDir)
        else:
            shutil.move(f, srcDir)
moveAlllFilesinDir(srcDir, dstDir)
```

- **This returned the following error:**

```
  File "C:\Users\jbla12\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\shutil.py", line 806, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'F1 converted' -> 'C:/Users/jbla12/Desktop/R Analyses/p65_project/sum_files\\F1 converted'
```

That's because that's a sub-folder I want it to go through! I've tried other methods but don't have record of them in my scripts.

Comment: Well, if `dstDir` doesn't exist, you need to create it first... See [`makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Comment: it does exist - I can screenshot to show that it's created exactly where specified

Comment: Missed that part of the code... Why not add a `print(csv_file)` inside the `glob` loop. Check if it even finds something

Comment: Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Comment: No I am saying that I made it in Windows. Unless it would visually show a folder and it not actually exist, I am not sure what else to say.

Comment: assuming that the folder exists, how can I modify the code to produce the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:**
Special thanks to "Automate the Boring Stuff"

```
import shutil
import os

dest = 'C:/Users/jbla12/Desktop/R Analyses/p65_project/sum_files/'
src = 'C:/Users/jbla12/Desktop/R Analyses/p65_project/'
txt_ID = 'statistics_Intensity_Sum_Ch=3_Img=1.csv'
def moveSpecFiles(txt_ID, src, dest):
    #src is the original file(s) destination
    #dest is the destination for the files to end up in
    #spec_txt is what the files end with that you want to ID
    for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(src):
        for file in filenames:
            if file.endswith(txt_ID):
                shutil.copy(os.path.join(foldername, file), dest)
    print('Your files are ready sir/madam!')


moveSpecFiles(txt_ID, src, dest)
```